# R: Plotting a scatterplot over a filled.contour plot

Tags: r, plot

I am very new to R and have made a filled.contour plot using interpolated data like the data found in [Plotting contours on an irregular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339296/plotting-contours-on-an-irregular-grid) .  Using some sample data from [Plotting contours on an irregular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339296/plotting-contours-on-an-irregular-grid) , I made a filled.contour and simple scatterplot using the following codes

```
x <- datr$Lat
y <- datr$Lon
z <- datr$Rain

require(akima)
fld <- interp(x,y,z)
filled.contour(fld)
plot(x,y)
```

Is there a way to make the plot(x,y) and filled.contour(fld) on the same plot (overlaying)?  I have tried the points(x,y), but this doesn't match the x and y axes.  In Matlab, I believe I would do this with hold, but I am unsure how to do it on R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the arguments `plot.title` or `plot.axes` for that:

```
x <- 10*1:nrow(volcano)
y <- 10*1:ncol(volcano)
filled.contour(x, y, volcano, plot.title = { 
  points(x = 200, y = 200)
})
```

([via](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-November/027375.html))

Comment: Huh, interesting, I got the desired result, but now I'm missing either my plot title or plot axes (depending on what argument I substituted).  Any suggestions on how to have it all?

Comment: Just add `title("my title")` before/after `points()`, or `axis(1); axis(2)` respectively.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solves your problem, you can "accept" it and close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to read the code for filled.contour, and do a
little hacking like so:

Make your figure:

```
filled.contour(fld)
```

Define these constants by copying them from the arguments list.

```
nlevels = 20
zlim = range(z, finite = TRUE)
las = 1 
levels = pretty(zlim, nlevels)
xlim = range(x, finite = TRUE)
ylim = range(y, finite = TRUE)
xaxs = "i"
yaxs = "i"
asp = NA
```

Calculate these values by copying code from the function body

```
mar.orig <- (par.orig <- par(c("mar", "las", "mfrow")))$mar
w <- (3 + mar.orig[2L]) * par("csi") * 2.54
```

Set the layout by copying code from the function body

```
layout(matrix(c(2, 1), ncol = 2L), widths = c(1, lcm(w)))
```

Noteice that the figure is actually plotted after the color scale, 
but we don't wnat to reverse the order of the layout because `layout` 
actually sets the 'current' region as the last region because the 
first call to `plot.new` will cause the current region to wrap around
to the first region.   Hence, when you set the plot window and plot the points via:

```
plot.window(ylim=ylim,xlim=xlim)
points(x,y)
title(main='title',
      sub='Sub-Title',
      xlab='This is the x axis',
      ylab='This is the y axis')
```

They overlay figure as desired.