# Contour plot is not been filled completely using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, contour

I'm trying to do my first ever filled contour plot using `ggplot`. With my data, I was specting something like:

[image]

But my result was:

```
a <- c(1, 1.1, 1, 1.3, 1.2, 2, 2.2, 2, 2.5, 2.1, 3, 3, 3, 3.1, 3.2)
b <- c(rep(c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), 3))
c <- seq(0, 1000, by = 1000/14)

DF <- data.frame(a, b, c)

ggplot(DF, aes(x = a, y = b, z = c)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = c)) +
  geom_contour() + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10))
```

[image]

What I'm doing wrong, and where I can find more datailed information about this plots?

Comment: for every value of `a` there should be all values of `b`. A viable approach is to use `expand.grid(a = a, b = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20))` and then generate `c`

Comment: @missuse How can I generate `c`?

Comment: Related [Plotting contours on an irregular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339296/plotting-contours-on-an-irregular-grid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

generate coordinates:

```
b = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20)
a = (1:30)/10
```

generate all combinations of coordinates

```
df <- expand.grid(a, b)
```

generate c via tcrossprod of a and b+1 (this is completely arbitrary but will generate a nice pattern)

```
df$c <- as.vector(a %o% (b+1))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, z = c, fill = c)) +
  geom_raster(interpolate = T) + #interpolate for success 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10))
```

[image]

generally if you have a matrix of values (z values) to be plotted in ggplot you will need to convert it to long format via `melt` in `reshape2` or gather in `tidyr` and then use for plotting.

Your data is very sparse, one approach to overcome this is to generate the missing data. I will show how to accomplish with loess function:

```
model <- loess(c ~ a + b, data = DF) #make a loess model based on the data provided (data in OP)

z <- predict(model, newdata = expand.grid(a = (10:30)/10, b = (0:200)/10)) #predict on the grid data

df <- data.frame(expand.grid(a = (10:30)/10, b = (0:200)/10), c = as.vector(z)) #append z to grid data

ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b, z = c, fill = c)) +
  geom_raster(interpolate = T)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you help me if my z vector is `c <- seq(0, 1000, by = 1000/14)`

Comment: Edited again, found a mistake in previous edit, `c` did not contain correct numbers.

Comment: But please, @daniel-valencia-c, don't use a rainbow color scheme.