# How to fill a map from a shapefile using its own attributes table in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, shapefile, qgis

I see some people using R to fill maps from shapefiles, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339663/7769755). With my R knowledge, I only read the shapefile and plot it.

With QGIS I added an extra column to the attribute table called "OCCURENCE". This column is a year when a specific event occurred. I'd like to fill each country according to the year of occurence using a color scale, leaving the countries with no data without fill. The folder with the shapefiles is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19_zXZJV0Pz8lc3CkixTswyp3GXz_ISxR?usp=sharing). As example, I added some years to a few countries, and I like to obtain something like:

[image] and a legend [image].

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

World <- readOGR(dsn = "mundo", layer = "mundo")
class(World)

World2 <- fortify(World)
class(World2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = World2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               colour = "black", size = 0.5, fill = "white")
```

[image]

Any help??

Comment: What choropleth answers on SO were unhelpful so we know what research you did for this heavily asked question and can then not spin cycles suggesting things you already knew/did.

Comment: In a simple way, you can use the `sf` package. `mydata <- st_read(dsn = ".", layer = "mundo");  ggplot() + geom_sf(data = mydata, aes(fill = OCCURENCE))`

Answer (score 3):

The simple way, as @jazzurro said, is to work with `sf` package. But, you can achieve this with the method proposed by you adding a couple of steps.

You need to add an `id` field in `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and join these attributes with `fortify()` product. With this, you can fill polygons with any field:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

World <- readOGR(dsn = "mundo", layer = "mundo")
class(World)

World2 <- fortify(World)
class(World2)

World@data$id <- 0:(dim(World@data)[1]-1) # add id field

World2_join = plyr::join(x = World2,y = World@data, by="id") # join by id

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = World2_join, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = OCCURENCE), # fill by OCCURENCE
               colour = "black", size = 0.5)
```

[image]