# Heatmap with locations in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, raster, stat-density2d

I am trying to plot a heatmap of a country with some points that are probabilities of occurrence of a event.
What I did up to now is next:

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
Uruguay  <- getData("GADM",country="Uruguay",level=0)
ggplot(Uruguay,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) + 
  ggplot2::lims(x = c(-60, -50), y = c(-35, -30))+
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill=id),color="grey30")+
  coord_map(xlim=c(-1,1)+bbox(Uruguay)["x",],ylim=c(-1,1)+bbox(Uruguay)["y",])+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide="none")+
  theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image: country border]

my data to produce the heatmap is

```
prob <- c(10,20,90,40)
lat <- c(-30.52,-32.04,-33.16,-34.28)
long <- c(-57.40,-55.45,-56.35,-56.40)
data <- data.frame(prob, lat, long)
```

I think that using `ggplot2::stat_density2d` and `ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn` is the way to go but I don't know how to implement it. I want to produce a heatmap like that

[image]

Any help is Welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To plot the example data you could just use plot

```
library(raster)
Uruguay  <- getData("GADM",country="Uruguay",level=0)
plot(Uruguay, col="orange")
```

As for the map you want to make, there are a lot of choices involved. But here is a basic example

```
prob <- c(10,20,90,40)
lat <- c(-30.52,-32.04,-33.16,-34.28)
long <- c(-57.40,-55.45,-56.35,-56.40)
data <- data.frame(prob, lat, long)

r <- raster(Uruguay, res=.5)
x <- rasterize(cbind(long, lat), r, prob)
plot(x)
lines(Uruguay)
```

Comment: but how can span I the colors to the rest of the territory?

Comment: You need to explicitly model the surface from the data you have.  Kriging, 2D convolution, etc.  Then you can plot.

Comment: I assumed you had many more observations. If you only have three points, what assumptions do you use to fill the gaps? See ?interpolate for technical possibilities, but whether these make sense is a very different type of question (methodological, not coding)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could get what I wanted. Henrik's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339296/plotting-contours-on-an-irregular-grid/19339663#19339663) was very helpful
I share the code with you

```
library(raster)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
Uruguay  <- getData("GADM",country="Uruguay",level=1)

#invented data
    prob <- c(5, 90,10,15,99,40,90,25,70,90)
    lat <- c(-31,-31.2,-31.3,-34,-32.5,-32.6,-33.7,-34.9,-34.2,-32.5)
    long <- c(-58.3,-55.1,-57.3,-58.4,-56.5,-54,-57.7,-55.8,-54.1,-53.5)
    prueba <- data.frame(prob, lat, long)
    


library(akima)
fld <- with(prueba, interp(x = long, y = lat, z = prob))

class(Uruguay)
uru <- fortify(Uruguay)

library(reshape2)

# prepare data in long format
df <- melt(fld$z, na.rm = TRUE)
names(df) <- c("x", "y", "prob")
df$long <- fld$x[df$x]
df$lat <- fld$y[df$y]


ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = uru, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               colour = "black", size = 0.5, fill = "white") +
  geom_tile(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat, z = prob, fill = prob), alpha = 0.8) +
  ggtitle("Frost probability") +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude") +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "Probability (%)",
                        low = "red", high = "blue") +
  theme_bw() +`enter code here`
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20, vjust = -0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, vjust = 0.2),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  coord_map()
```