# Develop a modified version of stat_contour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm ultimately trying to plot contour plots, or "raster plots", of irregular datasets - a rather common question of course. Many solutions propose to interpolate the data first, and then plot it, for instance here : [Plotting contours on an irregular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339296/plotting-contours-on-an-irregular-grid) amongst other - or in fact, the man page at https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html

However, for convenience I'm trying to wrap it into a new stat.

I managed to get something that works for geom_raster, simply lifting the interpolation code from the example in the manual:

```
require(akima)
StatInterpRaster <- ggproto("StatInterpRaster", Stat,
                           compute_group = function(data, scales) {
                             
                             ii<-akima::interp(x = data$x,
                                               y = data$y,
                                               z = data$fill)
                             
                             data.out <- tibble(x = rep(ii$x, nrow(ii$z)),
                                           y = rep(ii$y, each = ncol(ii$z)),
                                           fill = as.numeric(ii$z) )
                         
                             return(data.out)
                           },
                           
                           required_aes = c("x", "y", "fill")
)

stat_interp_raster<- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "contour",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                              inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatInterpRaster, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

which works as expected:

```
ee <- tibble (x=rnorm(50),y=rnorm(50),z=x*y)
ee %>% ggplot() + geom_raster(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z),stat=StatInterpRaster)
```

[image]

I would now trying to achieve the same thing with contours. Naively I tried

```
StatInterpContour <- ggproto("StatInterpContour", Stat,
                            compute_group = function(data, scales) {
                              
                              ii<-akima::interp(x = data$x,
                                                y = data$y,
                                                z = data$z)
                              
                              data.out <- tibble(x = rep(ii$x, nrow(ii$z)),
                                                 y = rep(ii$y, each = ncol(ii$z)),
                                                 z = as.numeric(ii$z) )
                              
                              #StatContour(data.out)
                              return(data.out)
                            },
                            
                            required_aes = c("x", "y", "z")
)

stat_interp_contour<- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "contour",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                              inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatInterpContour, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

which is essentially the same as above. However it does not produce the expected result :

```
 ee %>% ggplot() + geom_contour(aes(x=x,y=y,z=z),stat=StatInterpContour)
```

[image]

In retrospect, this is not surprising. My stat is generating a regular data array, with neatly ordered values in x and y, but nowhere am I generating the actual lines. The contour lines are more complicated, seem to be generated by  `xyz_to_isolines` in stat_contour (cf. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/stat-contour.r , line 97 as of today).

I could copy the relevant code in stat-contour.r, but it seems to me that it is a waste of effort and it would be better to simply pass my result to stat_contour, that already does the job: it generates contour lines from an object of that shape. So apparently I "just" have to call StatContour (or friends) somewhere in my `StatInterpContour` function `compute_group`  -- but how ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that you shouldn't need to copy code over from `StatContour`. Instead, make your `ggproto` class *inherit* from `StatContour`. Prepare the data then pass it, along with all necessary parameters, to the `compute_group` function from `StatContour`

```r
StatInterpContour <- ggproto("StatInterpRaster", StatContour,
  compute_group = function(data, scales, z.range, bins = NULL, binwidth = NULL, 
    breaks = NULL, na.rm = FALSE)  {
                             
    ii<-akima::interp(x = data$x,
                      y = data$y,
                      z = data$z)
    data <-  tibble(x = rep(ii$x, nrow(ii$z)),
             y = rep(ii$y, each = ncol(ii$z)),
             z = as.numeric(ii$z), group = 1) 
    StatContour$compute_group(data, scales, z.range, 
                  bins, binwidth, breaks, na.rm)
    
    },
    required_aes = c("x", "y", "z")
)
```

This requires a little modification of your user-facing function:

```
stat_interp_contour<- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "contour",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, 
                              show.legend = NA,
                              inherit.aes = TRUE, bins = NULL, binwidth = NULL, 
    breaks = NULL,  ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatInterpContour, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, bins = bins, binwidth = binwidth, 
    breaks = breaks,  ...)
  )
}
```

But should now work without as expected. Here, I've plotted it along with the original points coloured according to their z value to show that the contours try to approximate the level of the points:

```r
ee %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = z), size = 3) +
  stat_interp_contour(aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level))) +
  scale_color_viridis_c()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes ! That's the ticket, thanks. Indeed the call to StatContour$compute_group() was what I did not know how to do. Brilliant !